# How do I expand a node (parent node) in an ASP.NET Dynamic TreeView Control upon click of the text of the node?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a treeview control, the nodes and their children of which I populate on the server side from a `DataTable`.

How do I expand any node of the control upon click of it's rendered text?

Altering the `TreeNodeSelectAction` property of the node doesn't help.

I know that this property works for Tree View Controls that are not populated dynamically.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Share your code with the rest of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry forgot getting back to this. I messed around using the built in "TreeView_ToggleNode" javascript function, that gets rendered along with the TreeView Control. Got exactly what I needed.